# Java Change Color of Element on JTextPane using StyledDocument

Tags: java, swing, colors, styles, jtextpane

this is kinda overkill for me.. I am using a JTextPane for a chat, I have colors there.. What I want is, with reference to a element changing the color of it.. 
I am using StyledDocument, I have no clue how to do this..

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use setCharacterAttributes(). Define desired color in a SimpleAttributeSet using StyleConstants.setBackground()/setForeground(). Use Element's start and end offsets for the offset and length.

If the last attribute is false only thouse attributes of Element which are defined in the SimpleAttributeSet are replaced.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like what you asking for can be described in a single method, have a look :

```
private void appendToPane(JTextPane tp, String msg, Color c)
{
    StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
    AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, c);

    aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, "Lucida Console");
    aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.Alignment, StyleConstants.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);

    int len = tp.getDocument().getLength();
    tp.setCaretPosition(len);
    tp.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
    tp.replaceSelection(msg);
}
```

Just try to pass the reference of your `JTextPane` along with your `String` and respective `Colour` that you want to provide, to this method and see the magic :-)

Comment: Thanks , this is for inserting text with colors, I know mate. What I was looking was something to edit color on already inserted text, u see? StanislavL already helped me ;)
thank you

Comment: @TiagoM : Ahha, seems like I misunderstood the question :( , my bad, so Sorry for that.

Comment: @TiagoM : Hehe, Your are most Welcome and Keep Smiling :-)